# counting loop operator for

Tags: c, for-loop

I have to count the *for* operators that a person writes in the console, but I have to exclude the ones that are in comments - *//for* and */*for* shouldn't be counted.
Also the for's that are inside a multiline comment shouldn't be counted (until it is closed with **/*)

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
int flagcomment = 0;
char *pointerLine;
char string[130];
pointerLine = strtok(string, " (\t\n\b\r{}\\\'\";:)&^%$#@!~-+,.][_=");
while (pointerLine != 0)
{
    printf("%d",flagcomment);
    if (*pointerLine == '/' && *(pointerLine + 1) == '/')
        break;
    if (*pointerLine == 'for' && *(pointerLine + 1) == '"')
        break;
    if (*pointerLine == 'for' && *(pointerLine + 1) == '/')
        break;
    if (*pointerLine == '/' && *(pointerLine + 1) == '*' && (!flagcomment)) 
    { 
        flagcomment = 1; 
        break;
    }
    if (flagcomment==1)
    {
        if (*pointerLine == '*' && *(pointerLine + 1) == '/') 
        {
            flagcomment = 0;
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
```

It only works sometimes - When I write */*for* it stops counting them , but when it comes to end the multiline comment I write *for*/* but the for's I write after that are still uncounted, but it think that the flag should be 0 when it finds **/*. I can't understand why this isn't working, I would be grateful if someone helps me :)

Comment: Too many `break`s, I am sure you are not trying to compare `*pointerLine` to `'for'` which is a multicharacter constant and is implementation defined.

Comment: Look up the `strcmp()` function for comparing strings.

Comment: How would that even work partially? You confuse _string literals_ and _character constants_ and compare pointers, not "strings".

Comment: @Olaf: multi-character character (heh) constants are allowed in C, but their value is implementation-defined. I'm *guessing* they are allowed for ease of parsing and compiler extensions (e.g. perhaps a UTF-32 character constant if multi-byte?).

Comment: @TimČas: 1) As you write: The value is implementation defined (endianess, alignment within the `int`, encoding in general). 2) For UTF-16/32 `charN_t` exist. 3) `*pointerLine` is `char`, so comparing to an `int with more than a single character in the lower bits always fails. 4) I was in error about the pointer comparison. OP dereferences the pointer. This shows even more missconception about C "strings"/pointers & arrays than I initially thought.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that don't look right in your code, but this is the most important mistake

```
*pointerLine == 'for'
```

This comparison does not compare the word *for* to the content of `*pointerLine`, the `'for'` is a multicharacter constant that has an integral value, but that integral value is implementation defined.

You are comparing two *integers* that are unlikely to be equal, and most importantly you are not checking for the word *for*, doesn't your compiler warn about the *multicharacter constant*?

Also,

```
while (pointerLine != 0)
```

maybe you meant

```
while (*pointerLine != 0)
```

and you must check for `NULL` after `strtok()`.

I worte this on the fly, maybe it's correct test it and check

```
int
count_for_loops(const char *const string)
{
    int mlcomment; // Multiline Comments
    int ignoreline; // Comments
    int forcount; // for loops count

    mlcomment = 0;
    ignoreline = 0;
    forcount = 0;

    if ((string[0] == '\0') || (string[1] == '\0') || (string[2] == '\0'))
        return 0;

    for (size_t i = 0 ; string[i + 2] != '\0' ; ++i)
    {
        switch (string[i])
        {
        case '/':
            switch (string[i + 1])
            {
            case '*':
                mlcomment = 1;
                i += 1;
                break;
            case '/':
                ignoreline = 1;
                i += 1;
                break;
            }
            break;
        case '*':
            if (string[i + 1] == '/')
            {
                mlcomment = 0;
                i += 1;
            }
            break;
        case '\n':
            ignoreline = 0;
            break;
        case 'f':
            if ((mlcomment != 0) || (ignoreline != 0))
                continue;
            else if ((string[i + 1] == 'o') && (string[i + 2] == 'r'))
            {
                forcount +=  1;
                i += 2;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return forcount;
}
```

Comment: no, im using VS and how does it work then ? i mean if i write 'for' it counts it

Comment: I don't think it's really working. It can be a coincidence. To compare `"for"` the string to something you need to compare each indvidual character, or use `strcmp()` or `memcmp()`.

Comment: yes, i was afraid that i would have to compare each character, i tried like this cuz i thought it would be easier

Comment: It's not really hard, just not so easy.